# How to test React useEffect hooks with jasmine and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, jasmine, react-hooks, enzyme

I can't find how to call my useEffect hooks while testing my component.

I tried several solution like this one, but it didn't work: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act

My component :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: IDispatch, ownProps: ITextAreaOwnProps): ITextAreaDispatchProps => ({
        onMount: () => dispatch(addTextArea(ownProps.id)),
});

export const TextArea = (props) => {
        React.useEffect(() => {
            props.onMount();
        }, []);

        // more code... //

        return (
            <>
                <TextareaTagName
                    {...props.additionalAttributes}
                    className={props.className}
                />
                {props.children}
                {getValidationLabel()}
            </>
        );
    };
```

My test :

```
it('should call prop onMount on mount', () => {
    const onMount = jasmine.createSpy('onMount');

    mount(<TextArea id="textarea-id" onMount={onMount} />);

    expect(onMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: You can just add another call above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't test it directly. You basically need to trigger the change detection in your component to activate the `useEffect` hook. You can easily use the `react-dom/test-utils` library by doing something like this

```
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

it('should call prop onMount on mount', () => {
  const onMount = jasmine.createSpy('onMount');

  const wrapper = mount(<TextArea id="textarea-id" onMount={onMount} />);

  act(() => {
    wrapper.update();
  });

  expect(onMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the documentation, useEffect should update on any prop change.

1. You can just recall the test using other props.
2. You can mock the use effect.

```html
 /* mocking useEffect */
useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect");
mockUseEffect(); // 2 times
mockUseEffect(); //

const mockUseEffect = () => {
       useEffect.mockImplementationOnce(f => f());
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you can test the onMount function call is by calling the `wrapper.update()` method. You have to use `mount` from enzyme as `shallow` doesn't support calling hooks yet. More about the issue here -
[useEffect not called when the component is shallow rendered #2086](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086)

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

it('should call prop onMount on mount', () => {
  // arrange
  const onMount = jasmine.createSpy('onMount');
  const wrapper = mount(<TextArea id="textarea-id" onMount={onMount} />);

  // act
  wrapper.update();

  // assert
  expect(onMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

In case you are making an api call in the useEffect hook, you have to update the wrapper in setTimeout hook so that the changes are reflected on the component.

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

it('should call prop onMount on mount', () => {
  // arrange
  const onMount = jasmine.createSpy('onMount');
  const wrapper = mount(<TextArea id="textarea-id" onMount={onMount} />);

  setTimeout(() => {
      // act
      wrapper.update();

      // assert
      expect(onMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```